# How to store more than one value for same key in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a string named `InputRow`, which looks like this:

```
1,Kit,23
2,Ret,211
```

I apply the Regex `(.+),(.+),(.+)` on it and store the results in multiple variables.

For the first line `1,kit,23` I get:

```
InputRow.1-->1
InputRow.2-->kit
InputRow.3-->23
```

For the second line `2,Ret,211` I get:

```
InputRow.1-->2
InputRow.2-->Ret
InputRow.3-->211
```

I want to store all input rows in a `HashMap` with the same key `InputRow`. How can I do that in Java?

My Java Code is..,

```
line="1,Kit,23";
final Map<String, String> regexResults = new HashMap<>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+),(.+),(.+)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.find()) 
{
final String baseKey = "InputRow";
for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
final String key = new StringBuilder(baseKey).append(".").append(i).toString();
 String value = matcher.group(i);
if (value != null) {
   regexResults.put(key, value);
}
}
```

Now i wants to store the second row also in "regexResults" to process.How it is possible?

Comment: Not excatly sure what your examples are showing, but to store more than one key is achievable with a custom class holding those fields.

Comment: post what have you done so far..

Comment: Share your code with us, but first read about `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods which should help you putting values in `HashMap` while overriding them in the specified class

Comment: @Jobin I have posted my code in which tried

Comment: Still, you cannot store multiple entries for one key as already answered here multiple times, the only possibility is using a container like `List`, as I described in my answer below.

Comment: @thatguy Thanks for your code it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class `InputRow`:

```
class InputRow {

    private int value1;
    private String value2;
    private int value3;

    //...getters and setters

}
```

and a `HashMap<Integer, List<InputRow>>`. The hash map key is your row index and you assign all matching rows as a `List<InputRow>` to the hash map.

For clarification, a `HashMap` stores **one** entry for **one unique** key. Therefore, you cannot assign more than one entry to the same key or else the entry will just be overwritten. So, you need to write a container to cover multiple objects or use an existing like `List`.

**Example for your code**

I used both of your text fragments, separated by a newline character, so two lines. This snippet puts two `InputRow` objects in a list into the `HashMap` with the key "InputRow". Note, that the matcher group index starts at `1`, zero refers to the whole group. Also mind that for simplicity I assumed you created a `InputRow(String, String, String)` constructor.

```
String line = "1,Kit,23\n2,Ret,211";

final Map<String, List<InputRow>> regexResults = new HashMap<>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+),(.+),(.+)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

List<InputRow> entry = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    entry.add(new InputRow(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3)));
}

regexResults.put("InputRow", entry);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. A Map can only store one key per definition. The documentation says

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

The only thing you can do is map the key to a List of values. `Map<String, List<String>>`. Then it could look like this

```
InputRow.1 --> [1, kit, 23],
InputRow.2 --> [2, Ret, 211]
```